# How can I prevent bubbled events after I set focus to a textarea?

Tags: javascript, extjs, textarea, event-bubbling

I have the following:

```
xtype: 'gridpanel',
id: 'myGridPanel',
columns: [...],
store: myStore,
listeners: {
  select: function(){
    Ext.getCmp('myTextArea').focus();
    console.log('Text area has focus here');
  }
}
```

`myTextArea` has focus right after I call `.focus()` but when my program execution leaves the select function it loses focus.  I think the problem is that there is program execution that happens after the select listener gets called and that execution is changing the focus.  How do I prevent the bubbled events from changing focus?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation ? of course, your other event code will have to be somewhat sensible for this to work as expected (no timeouts).

Comment: I'm not really sure what I would call that on... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` event fires before the row gets highlighted graphically. I assume that's when the focus gets set to something else (the selected row), as happens a lot in Ext.js code.

You have different options to try (haven't tried them right now, just recollecting from memory):

1. Use the `beforeselect` event and return `false`, then the underlying selection will be cancelled. This only works if you don't need the actual row selection. This is equivalent to stopping event bubbling as you asked.
2. Use a timeout, e.g. `Ext.util.DelayedTask` and wait a few milliseconds before you set focus to the textarea. In this case you preserve the underlying row selection. This might be your best option.
3. Play with the `selectionchange` event. It might behave differently regarding timing.